# How to change the URL param by JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript

I need to change URL param (step=?) By JavaScript only.

My URL is,

```
http://domain.com/path/to/reach/5?step=1
```

I want to change the param '**step**' by JavaScript only.

I need like this,

```
http://domain.com/path/to/reach/5?step=1
http://domain.com/path/to/reach/5?step=2
http://domain.com/path/to/reach/5?step=3
```

I use some validations (show/hide) via **step** param only.

So I need refresh also, but this changes should stable.

I found lot of examples, those all are done by jQuery.

But I need it, only on JavaScript.

Comment: But i don't want jQuery based solution.

Comment: Have you used `window.history.pushState`?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, Nope i'm not use that. What it does actually ?

Comment: Never mind. I gave a solution, which worked. But looks like you just chose an answer. `:D`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the (rather-new) URL api:

```
var url = new URL(location.href)
url.searchParams.set('step', '...')

var modifiedUrl = url.toString();
```

If you're concerned about browser support, consider using a [polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/url.js):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```js
location.search = " your query"
```